# web proxy handling window.location redirecting

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, location

I'm working on a web proxy and I have problem when a sites is using javascript redirect by doing a

```
window.location = "http://newurl.com";
```

Is there some way to intercept this and rewrite the url to this format "proxt?url=http://newurl.com"

In Firefox its easy,

```
function locationWatcher(id, oldURL, newURL) {
     return parseURL(newURL);
  }

window.watch('location', locationWatcher);
```

But the problem is that I need it to be working under IE.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy can rewrite the HTML, but that is very very hard to do correctly.

Writing an addon that does this for IE is also very very difficult to do correctly.

How do you handle redirects that use META refresh?